# How to save compounding attributes in godot

Tags: godot-3

I a have button that increases compounding stats with a rate of diminishing returns, I'm using it to test the saving system.

every time i click on the button it deletes 1 attribute points and increases vitality by a percentage

then the script gets the player.initial_maxhealth from another node and multiplies it by the total totalvitality of this node to get the totalmaxhealth on the player node....

as simple as it can be

my save and load system works.. kinda

```
func get_save_stats():
return {
    'filename': get_filename(),
    'parent': get_parent().get_path(),
    'vitality': vitality,
    'coefficient': coefficient,
    ..........and so on....
}

func load_save_stats(stats):
vitality = stats.vitality
coefficient = stats.coefficient
regenerationRate = stats.regenerationRate
attributePointsSpent .....
totalvitality.....
updateVitality()
```

it does save all the attributes that it needs to save... but if i press the button again
vitality reverts to the baseline....

i added a function to update the vitality to totalvitality after the load function, and it didn't work.

**PROBLEM**:

1)i increase attributes

2)i save the file

3)i load the file

4)the loaded file saved the new stats except one

5)clicking the increase attribute button, refreshes the vitality to baseline

6)all attributes point spent have been saved, just like anything else... saving literally deletes your points forever.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So big question now... how do i make it so that after attribute points have been spent, and thus lost forever... the attribute can never revert back to the baseline of 1.0?

Comment: for now i fixed the problem by using a persistence.gd script where the variables are saved.... but this only works for singleplayer so I'll need two instances of the player.tscn one for multiplayer and one for singleplayer

Comment: Can you edit your title to something that might be useful to others looking for this question in future?

Comment: If something is resetting after saving/ loading, you are not assigning the correct values back. Everything that you need for your calculation needs to be saved. There should be no difference if you click save twice and once load or three times in a row the load button. You need to narrow down the error, are the values wrong after loading? Are the correct values in your save file? Is your calculation using the correct values?

Comment: @Zibelas everything is as simple as : click button  > player points -1, attribute points + 1  > apply formula... and as of saving...every single variable in the script is also in the save function and the load function so nothing is missing

Comment: If everything is as simple as it is, it should work. Since it does not work, the simple code has a bug. To find the bug, find out which part is not producing the correct result. To help you, post the part that is not producing that correct part.

Comment: @Zibelas after wasting almost 4 hours i rage quit last night and now I'm back on working on the UI, so all the code is deleted